# htaccess rewrite using fake directory as params

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried doing a lot of research on this but nothing I seem to do works so I'm coming here for help.  I'm trying to do the following:

request: `/rss/40.6,-73.4`

rewrite: `/php/autoFeed.php?coords=40.6,-73.4`

My regex [that matches](https://regex101.com/r/kL5vM4/1) the coords is `^\/rss\/([\-]?\d+\.\d{1},[\-]?\d+\.\d{1})$` though I understand I don't need to escape the directory slashes.  That still didn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/rss/([\-]?\d+\.\d{1},[\-]?\d+\.\d{1})$ /php/autoFeed.php?coords=$1 [NC, L]
```

Do I need a `RewriteCond`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just simplify your regex and rule to:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^rss/([^/]+)/?$ /php/autoFeed.php?coords=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

For precise matching you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^rss/(-?\d+\.\d+,-?\d+\.\d+)/?$ /php/autoFeed.php?coords=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Precise matching seemed to work perfectly (the simple one didn't work right).